# Unable to solve "TypeError: Invalid shape (512, 256, 2) for image data" for VGG19

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytorch, torch

I'm unable to resolve the error for the forllowing code, I have a VGG19 encoder and a GetFusedImage class using pytorch.

CODE:

```
import argparse
import cv2
import numpy as np
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
from torchvision.models.vgg import vgg19
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pywt
import pywt.data

# Defining a custom pre-trained model (VGG19)
class VGG19(torch.nn.Module):

    def __init__(self, device='cpu'):
        super(VGG19, self).__init__()
        modelFeatures = list(vgg19(pretrained=True).features) # Extracting the feature of the model
        if device == "cuda":
            self.features = nn.ModuleList(modelFeatures).cuda().eval()
        else:
            self.features = nn.ModuleList(modelFeatures).eval()

    def forward(self, image):
        featureMaps = [] # List used to store the output of the each layer of the VGG19 model
        for index, layer in enumerate(self.features):
            image = layer(image)
            if index == 3:
                featureMaps.append(image)
        return featureMaps

class GetFusedImage:

    def __init__(self, CTscanImage, MRIscanImage):
        """
        Class Fusion constructor

        Instance Variables:
            self.images: input images
            self.model: CNN model, default=vgg19
            self.device: either 'cuda' or 'cpu'
        """
        self.inputImages = CTscanImage, MRIscanImage
        self.device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
        self.model = VGG19(self.device)

    def _RGB_to_YCbCr(self, img_RGB):
            """
            A private method which converts an RGB image to YCrCb format
            """
            img_RGB = img_RGB.astype(np.float32) / 255.
            return cv2.cvtColor(img_RGB, cv2.COLOR_RGB2YCrCb)

    def _YCbCr_to_RGB(self, img_YCbCr):
            """
            A private method which converts a YCrCb image to RGB format
            """
            img_YCbCr = img_YCbCr.astype(np.float32)
            return cv2.cvtColor(img_YCbCr, cv2.COLOR_YCrCb2RGB)

    def _is_gray(self, img):
            """
            A private method which returns True if image is gray, otherwise False
            """
            if len(img.shape) < 3:
                return True
            if img.shape[2] == 1:
                return True
            b, g, r = img[:,:,0], img[:,:,1], img[:,:,2]
            if (b == g).all() and (b == r).all():
                return True
            return False

    def _softmax(self, tensor):
            """
            A private method which compute softmax ouput of a given tensor
            """
            tensor = torch.exp(tensor)
            tensor = tensor / tensor.sum(dim=1, keepdim=True)
            return tensor

    def _tranfer_to_tensor(self):
            """
            A private method to transfer all input images to PyTorch tensors
            """
            self.images_to_tensors = []
            for image in self.normalized_images:
                np_input = image.astype(np.float32)
                if np_input.ndim == 2:
                    np_input = np.repeat(np_input[None, None], 3, axis=1)
                else:
                    np_input = np.transpose(np_input, (2, 0, 1))[None]
                if self.device == "cuda":
                    self.images_to_tensors.append(torch.from_numpy(np_input).cuda())
                else:
                    self.images_to_tensors.append(torch.from_numpy(np_input))

    def fuseAlgorithm(self):
        """
        Perform fusion algorithm
        """
        with torch.no_grad():

            imageSumMaps = [-1 for tensor_img in self.images_to_tensors]
            for idx, tensor_img in enumerate(self.images_to_tensors):
                imageSummaps[idx] = []
                featureMaps = self.model(tensor_img)
                for featureMap in featureMaps:
                    sumMap = torch.sum(featureMap, dim=1, keepdim=True)
                    imageSumMaps[index].append(sumMap)

            maxFusion = None

            for sumMaps in zip(*imageSumMaps):
            
                features = torch.cat(sumMaps, dim=1)
                weights = self._softmax(F.interpolate(features,
                                        size=self.images_to_tensors[0].shape[2:]))
                weights = F.interpolate(weights,
                                        size=self.images_to_tensors[0].shape[2:])
                currentFusion = torch.zeros(self.images_to_tensors[0].shape)
                for index, tensor_img in enumerate(self.images_to_tensors):
                    currentFusion += tensor_img * weights[:,index]
                if maxFusion is None:
                    maxFusion = currentFusion
                else:
                    maxFusion = torch.max(maxFusion, currentFusion)

            output = np.squeeze(maxFusion.cpu().numpy())
            if output.ndim == 3:
                output = np.transpose(output, (1, 2, 0))
            return output

    def fuseImage(self):
        """
        A top level method which fuse self.images
        """
        # Convert all images to YCbCr format
        self.normalizedImages = [-1 for img in self.inputImages]
        self.YCbCrImages = [-1 for img in self.inputImages]

        #checking if the image is grayscale or not
        for index, img in enumerate(self.inputImages):
            if not self._is_gray(img):
                self.YCbCrImages[index] = self._RGB_to_YCbCr(img)
                self.normalizedImages[index] = self.YCbCrImages[index][:, :, 0] #storingthe first channel of YCbCr image
            else:
                self.normalizedImages[index] = img / 255.
       
        # Transfer all images to PyTorch tensors (arrays)
        self._tranfer_to_tensor()

        # Perform fuse strategy
        fusedImage = self.fuseAlgorithm()[:, :, 0]

        # Reconstruct fused image given rgb input images
        for index, img in enumerate(self.inputImages):
            if not self._is_gray(img):
                self.YCbCrImages[index][:, :, 0] = fusedImage
                fusedImage = self._YCbCr_to_RGB(self.YCbCr_images[idx])
                fusedImage = np.clip(fusedImage, 0, 1)

        return (fusedImage * 255).astype(np.uint8)
        # return fused_img

    def waveletTransformation(self, image, imageName):

        titles = ['Approximation', ' Horizontal detail',
                  'Vertical detail', 'Diagonal detail']
        coeffs2 = pywt.dwt2(image, 'haar')

        LL, (LH, HL, HH) = coeffs2

        fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12, 3))
        for i, a in enumerate([LL, LH, HL, HH]):
            ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 4, i + 1)
            ax.imshow(a, interpolation="nearest", cmap=plt.cm.gray)

            if "CTscanImage" in imageName:
                path='jpg/ct_'+str(i)+'.jpg'
                cv2.imwrite(path,a)

            else:
                path='jpg/mri_'+str(i)+'.jpg'
                cv2.imwrite(path,a)

            ax.set_title(titles[i], fontsize=10)
            ax.set_xticks([])
            ax.set_yticks([])

        fig.tight_layout()
        plt.show()


if __name__ == "__main__":

    arg = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    arg.add_argument("--pathInCTImage", help="Path to CT Scan Image")
    arg.add_argument("--pathInMRIImage", help="Path to MRI Scan Image")
    args = arg.parse_args()

    CTscanImage = cv2.imread(args.pathInCTImage)
    MRIscanImage = cv2.imread(args.pathInMRIImage) #MRI Image will be registered

    handler = GetFusedImage(CTscanImage, MRIscanImage)

    handler.waveletTransformation(CTscanImage, "CTscanImage")
    handler.waveletTransformation(MRIscanImage, "MRIscanImage")
```

ERROR:

```
/Users/jaskiratsingh/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torchvision/models/_utils.py:208: UserWarning: The parameter 'pretrained' is deprecated since 0.13 and may be removed in the future, please use 'weights' instead.
  warnings.warn(
/Users/jaskiratsingh/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torchvision/models/_utils.py:223: UserWarning: Arguments other than a weight enum or `None` for 'weights' are deprecated since 0.13 and may be removed in the future. The current behavior is equivalent to passing `weights=VGG19_Weights.IMAGENET1K_V1`. You can also use `weights=VGG19_Weights.DEFAULT` to get the most up-to-date weights.
  warnings.warn(msg)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jaskiratsingh/Desktop/registration_fusion/fusion.py", line 223, in <module>
    handler.waveletTransformation(CTscanImage, "CTscanImage")
  File "/Users/jaskiratsingh/Desktop/registration_fusion/fusion.py", line 190, in waveletTransformation
    ax.imshow(a, interpolation="nearest", cmap=plt.cm.gray)
  File "/Users/jaskiratsingh/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/_api/deprecation.py", line 456, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/jaskiratsingh/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 1412, in inner
    return func(ax, *map(sanitize_sequence, args), **kwargs)
  File "/Users/jaskiratsingh/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py", line 5488, in imshow
    im.set_data(X)
  File "/Users/jaskiratsingh/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/image.py", line 715, in set_data
    raise TypeError("Invalid shape {} for image data"
TypeError: Invalid shape (512, 256, 2) for image data
```

The images which I passed are the following: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1ILFu0LVHOEHpcjpBPrLvCH3VPTprhiGf?usp=share_link

I tried changing the shape as well but that also didn't work for me.

Comment: Matplotlib's `pyplot.imshow` can plot images of dimension `(N,M)` (grayscale) or `(N,M,3) ` (rgb color), is there a reason you are doing grayscale on a 2 dimension image?

Comment: have you try applying `numpy.squeeze()` to it?